# Fail to create custom UI component in ZK framework

Tags: zk

Trying to create custom UI component going through ZK 6.0.1 Component Development Essentials.
Always got error in logs "http://localhost:8080/zk6/zkau/web/_zv2011051111/js/examples.com.foo.wpd : **HTTP Status 404 - /js/examples.com.foo.wpd**" when trying to use custom component. 
Found the war file with this example in scala, it works OK. I have copied all files from it to my project, and got same error.
The project structure is according to tutorial. What might be wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the **web** folder, which contains the js files, in the java classpath, that means it should be put under the **src** folder. More easy way is to use the [ZK Maven Archetype](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Quick_Start/Create_and_Run_Your_First_ZK_Application_with_Eclipse_and_Maven) to create the template for you.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But moving web directory to src doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

At least the way IntelliJ IDEA does things (which I see your are using, as am I), simply placing the `web` folder under the `src` folder doesn't seem to automatically get it copied to the artifact (although I'm not sure why).  So I tried manually putting it in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder, and that worked.  So the correct path for your example is `<project-root>/web/WEB-INF/classes/web/js/examples/com/foo/zk.wpd`.